# stored procedure and passing parameters to crystal report state

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports-2010

I develop with vb.net and I created a state with crystal report, I use a stored procedure and I would like to know how to pass parameters of the procedure in the state
thank you

Comment: Show the code you have tried and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: sorry, I could not post the code too many characters I think.When I print the state I have a window that appears asking me the parameters that I want to pass in the code.

Comment: Not all the code; just the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: hello, the problem is that I do not know the syntax to pass parameters with vb.net in a state, I searched on the internet but I did not find anything

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: report.SetParameterValue("@codmag", cmbmag.selectedvalue)

Comment: but I still have the window that appears before printing asking me to enter the value of the parameter

Comment: Did you add @codmag at design time? It has been many years since I used Crystal. See if someone with more recent experience can help. Post your code as part of your question.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me